# HHVM inside Docker always running as root

Tags: docker, hhvm

I'm running below command inside the docker container

**ps -ef | grep hhvm**

The result are :

**root         1     0  0 01:50 ?        00:00:00 hhvm --mode=server --user=www-data --port=9001 --config=/etc/hhvm/server.ini --config=/etc/hhvm/php.ini --config=/etc/hhvm/config.hdf
root        15     8  0 01:58 ?        00:00:00 grep hhvm**

Is this HHVM bug if running inside Docker, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I'm solving it by installing Supervisor inside the same Docker container, and start the HHVM using it.

Following supervisor.conf

```
[program:hhvm]
command=hhvm --mode=server --user=www-data --port=9001 --config=/etc/hhvm/server.ini --config=/etc/hhvm/php.ini --config=/etc/hhvm/config.hdf
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
```

Result:

```
www-data     9     1  3 02:21 ?        00:00:01 hhvm --mode=server --user=www-data --port=9001 --config=/etc/hhvm/server.ini --config=/etc/hhvm/php.ini --config=/etc/hhvm/config.hdf
root        20    12  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 grep hhvm
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this.